# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction. A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to develop Spring+Hibernate+EntityManager+Spring Data+PostgreSQL database on Spring Tools Suite and Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition. My configuration is:
applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.me, dk.me" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="dk.me.data"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
</jpa:repositories>
<!-- tx:jta-transaction-manager /-->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPU"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

and my persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="masterkey"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>           
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value = "org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
        <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value = "postgres"/>
        <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value = "masterkey"/>
        <!-- property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"/-->
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" 
        value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Code is pretty straightforware, there is simple call the the Spring Data repository to read all beans. The error messsage is:

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
```

And stack trace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:430)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.findAll(Unknown Source)
at dk.nmc.imarket.framework.services.FrameworkService.getAll(FrameworkService.java:32)
at dk.nmc.imarket.web.framework.FrameworkListFrame.getAll(FrameworkListFrame.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:730)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:729)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:575)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:355)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:579)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:220)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:192)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.nmc.nxapps.web.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:33)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1368)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:110)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
... 72 more
```

The question is - does my configuration make some sende, what should be corrected. I am aware that there are a lot of design choices (e.g. local vs. distributed transactions, use of data sources and so on), but I would like to arrive at the configuration that is the most similar to the current one, to proceed smoothly with the development itself. I am using the most recent compatible (4.x) versionas of Spring and Hibernate, there are no version conflicts in pom.xml and there are no mavan package or deploy time exceptions. The exception is raised when the first request is made at runtime.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: You configure a transaction manager for local transaction but tell the entitymanagerfactory to use JTA. So what is it. So no your config doesn't make sense and that is also what the exception is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

Your Spring transaction manager is JpaTransactionManager

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

while the persistence.xml is configured to use JTA:

```
<persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
```

You also use `hibernate.connection` properties which are meaningful for RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions.

1. If you don't want to use the JBoss XA `DataSource` and JTA transactions then just change the persistence-unit `transaction-type` to RESOURCE_LOCAL:

   ```
   <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   ```

   and remove this property:

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" 
   value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
   ```
2. If you want JTA then you need to configure a Spring [`JTATransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) and remove the local DataSource related `hibernate.connection` properties, while using JNDI to locate the JBoss XA DataSource:

   ```
   <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
   ```